# What exactly is the difference between different difficulty levels in single player?

Tags: sacred-2

Since monsters level with you, then what actually makes the difficulty levels different? I know that you need to finish the campaign at an easier difficulty in order to unlock the next difficulty, but other than this cosmetic requirement, what actually sets the difficulty levels apart? What would a level 80 player experience differently if he decides to replay Bronze difficulty than to play Niobium difficulty?